# How to upload data to Google Cloud Storage Automatically

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cloud, google-cloud-storage

I want to upload data from my local to oogle Cloud Storage, but I can't find any Java sample code describing how to do this. Would someone please give me some hint as how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean to upload from your computer to cloud storage? if so, why not upload manually through the console?

Comment: Yes, I want to upload from my computer. I am building a soft using Cloud and our expection is everything will do automatically not manually :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make use of Google Cloud Storage Java API. This might help you.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/
https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/photofeed/uploadphotos

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to implement :)

Comment: Welcome user3737020 !

Comment: I am trying to do step by step with the following link as below :
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted

Firstly, I tried to run LocalExample.java file But I got error when running :(

Do you have ever run this file ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/utils/SystemProperty
 at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceFactory.createRawGcsService(GcsServiceFactory.java:45)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceFactory.createGcsScom.google.appengine.demos.LocalExample.main(LocalExample.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty

Comment: Could you please tell me the Appengine sdk version ?

Comment: Currently, I am using Appengine sdk version 1.9.6

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow make the files accessible to the app. Then, simply [fetch](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/) it and [save to cloud storage](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/).